# separate Docker container logs for tomcat and application to aws cloudwatch logs

Tags: docker, log4j, docker-compose, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

By default docker container logs everything to stdout and thus in turn that could be send to different logs driver, so I am using awslogs driver and logging it to aws cloudwatch. (https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/awslogs/)

```
Docker-compose logging part looks like below

 logging:
  driver: 'awslogs'
options:
    awslogs-region: '${REGION}'
    awslogs-group: '-${xxxx}'
    awslogs-stream: '${xxxx}_xxx_aap
```

Now as this is a tomcat container which is hosting my app, and I am getting everything logged to stdout via log4j config. I want to have a way to segregate logs of tomcat and my web app in different awslog-group. So I was wondering is their possibility of doing it via any configuration in docker-compose ?  or any other way ?

Comment: Did you get a solution? I also have a similar problem. Can you please post some update here?